# Appcelerator Python Application Requires Silverlight?

Tags: python, silverlight, client-side, appcelerator

Something that I couldn't understand from appcelerator website:

If I use appcelerator to write a client-side python application for the web, will it require that users have silverlight installed on their machines?

Comment: Where are you getting this information from, a link to the documentation in question could be very helpful.

Comment: @Brian I got this idea from this sentence:
"AppCelerator's Titanium provides support for <script type="text/python"> ... </script>, using IronPython and Silverlight. " which is written in "Embedding Python inside Web Browsers" section in http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebBrowserProgramming. It says that it uses silverlight, but I was not sure whether users need to install silverlight on their machines, or maybe a different plugin from appcelerator, or maybe silverlight is somehow embedded inside the website itself. Anyway, I got the answer from appcelerator developer center now.

Comment: Apparently I can't answer my own question for 8 hours, so i'll have to wait a bit before answering.

Comment: I eagerly await but I don't think you need IronPython to use Appcelerator, I just think you need to put it in the script and it's good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from appcelerator developer center:

> The php/python/ruby scripts are
>   executed in the context of the
>   Titanium Desktop. So you will need to
>   run it inside a session of Ti Desktop
>   application, and not on a webpage.
>
> Ti Desktop is a modified webkit that
>   knows how to handle this scripts.

So apparently this tag is not for websites.